# Structure entries bug

Tags: structure, entries, navigation, bug

I am using Structure Entries and trying to use hide from nav. This works well when I'm trying to hide an entry on ground level, but when I'm trying to hide a sub item the whole menu collapses. I'm not doing anything weird and just copied the 4th example.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that Structure Entries does not support the option to hide children from navigation. I found a plugin for Structure that does support this, and makes it possible to create more complicated navigations for your website (like Structure Entries). Here's the link to the plugin: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/structure-nav